# How do i add a description for the pictures when you click on them in javafx.

Tags: java, javafx

Here is what I got so far

```
package photo.album;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * enter code here
 */
public class PhotoAlbum extends Application {

    Button btnTree, btnFwheel, btnAlley, btnFrog, btnPic, btnRemove;
        ImageView imgpic;
        HBox btnbox;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        btnTree = new Button("Palmetto Tree");
        btnFwheel = new Button("Ferris Wheel");
        btnAlley = new Button("Alley Way");
        btnFrog = new Button("Little Frog");
        btnPic = new Button("Picture");
        btnRemove = new Button("Remove");

        btnTree.setOnAction(e->handleButtonAction(e));
        btnFwheel.setOnAction(e->handleButtonAction(e));
        btnAlley.setOnAction(e->handleButtonAction(e));
        btnFrog.setOnAction(e->handleButtonAction(e));
        btnPic.setOnAction(e->handleButtonAction(e));
        btnRemove.setOnAction(e->handleButtonAction(e));


        //put top 5 buttons in a box
        btnbox = new HBox(btnTree, btnFwheel, btnAlley, btnFrog, btnPic);
        btnbox.setSpacing(10);
        btnbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        // make the image
        imgpic = new ImageView();

        //create the BorderPane
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        root.setTop(btnbox);
        root.setCenter(imgpic);
        root.setBottom(btnRemove);

        //center the button in the bottom region
        BorderPane.setAlignment(btnRemove, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 800);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Photo Album");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


    }

    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Image img;
        if(event.getSource() == btnTree)
           img = new Image("file:///../image/Tree.jpg");


        else if(event.getSource() == btnFwheel)
           img = new Image("file:///../image/Fwheel.png");


        else if(event.getSource() == btnAlley)
           img = new Image("file:///../image/Alley.jpg");


        else if(event.getSource() == btnFrog)
           img = new Image("file:///../image/Frog.png");

        else if(event.getSource() == btnPic)
           img = new Image("file:///../image/Pic.jpg");


        else
           img = null;
        imgpic.setImage(img);

    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

I can't seem to get it right. I'm just want to be able to show a description about the photo when clicked on them. If anyone can lead me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It depends where you like to put the description. If you like to show it on top of the image you could use a [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) to place text above the image. In case you want to display it under the image just put your image into a [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) with an addional label so when you click the image you could set the text.

Comment: Show the description when clicked on what??? The button or the `ImageView`. Also how should the description be shown? A new window? Somewhere in the scene? Some other way? Furthermore: How do you stroe the description?